# Disable the sd card emulation and use only the external sd card?

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, sd-card

My Mother has a Samsung tablet, which is not rooted.

She always gets confused with the different sdcard locations, as some apps store their data on the physical sdcard and others drop data to the emulated one.

I may be able to copy all data from the emulated sdcard to the physical sdcard, but wonder whether there is a possibility to deactivate the emulated card in favor of the external card. There is plenty of space on the external sdcard, so I don't see the point in using up the internal memory by storing to the emulated card.

What I'm looking for is a solution that in a way links the emulated storage to the physical device.